# Why can't I access a global variable in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

In the code below, I can't access "colors" from within a function, but I can access "numColors".  The getColors() function seems to set the array properly but the init() function can't access it, as seen by the alert statement results.

The page can be called with a parameter string such as "?colors=0000FF|FF0000".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>

<script>

( function () {

        var colors = [];
        var numColors;

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false );        

        function init() {   
            colors = getColors()

            alert(numColors);
            alert(colors);
        }

        function getColors() {
            var data = getURLParameter('colors');
            var list = data.split('|');

            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                colors.push(list[i]);
            }

            numColors = colors.length;

            alert(numColors);
            alert(colors);
        }


        // from http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

        function getURLParameter(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");

            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );

            var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );

            if (results == null) {
                return "";
            } else {
                return results[1];      
            }
        }

} ) ();

</script>            

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens when you `alert(colors)`?

Comment: What do you mean "as seen by the alert statement results"? What are you seeing?

Comment: Notice: `colors` and `numColors` are _not_ global variables, rather closure variables.

Answer (score 3):

`getColors` modifies `colors` when it runs, and then you overwrite `colors` with the return value of `getColors()` which (since it lacks a `return` statement) is `undefined`.

Remove the assignment:

```
function init() {   
    getColors()
```

Or change `getColors` so it uses a local variable and then returns it.

Answer (score 2):

Your getColors() function isn't returning anything, yet you're assigning a value to it when you say:

```
colors = getColors();
```

I think this would work if you just called:

```
getColors();
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your `init()` function be

```
function init() {   
    getColors();

    alert(numColors);
    alert(colors);
 }
```

You are setting `colors` to the return value of the `getColors` function. However, you do not return a value so `colors` will be set to `undefined`.